# Facebook “publish_actions” permission

Tags: publish-actions

A follow-up to someone else's question:
I can't publish anything on user timeline when facebook has remove "publish_actions" permission? If it can,how to upload video on user timeline?Or how to review "publish_actions" permission with Graph API v2.12

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can no longer upload video or media to user's timeline as Facebook removed publish_actions permission. There is no alternative to this as of now. You cannot give review for this permission since this no longer exists.

You can however share links to user's timeline via [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/)